# What type of magic square is this?

Tags: mathematics, magic-square

[image: Magic square]

What type of magic square is this?

Comment: Shouldn't the entry "23" (row 4, column 4) be "33"?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Is it "is there a name for a magic square where some lines add up to one thing and some to another with a 'missing' number"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The given square $X$ results from the following classical magic square (which arranges the number $1,2,\ldots,25$ in a $5\times5$ square so that every row, every column, and each of the two main diagonals adds up to the magical sum 65)

$\displaystyle\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
15&16&22& 3& 9\\
 2& 8&14&20&21\\
19&25& 1& 7&13\\
 6&12&18&24& 5\\
23& 4&10&11&17
\end{array}\right]$

by subtracting 1 from every entry, adding 10 times a permutation matrix, and finally supressing the resulting 0-entry in the center of the square:

$\displaystyle X=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
15&16&22& 3& 9\\
 2& 8&14&20&21\\
19&25& 1& 7&13\\
 6&12&18&24& 5\\
23& 4&10&11&17
\end{array}\right] -
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1&1
\end{array}\right] +
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
0&0&10&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&10\\ 
0&10&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&10&0\\ 
10&0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right]
$

Comment: +1 for this, but you should probably add a note that it assumes the 23 in the question's square to be wrong.

Comment: Thanks , but i didn't understand the part of adding 10 times a permutation matrix